# Audio chatting and phone calls through browser

Tags: ruby, audio, streaming, voip, sip

If I want to create online phone for small office with web client (through Astrisk/Adhearsion) how can I stream IN/OUT audio right in my browser (like GTalk do). Preferably without Java applets and without Flash.

I need to get voice stream from Astriks call, stream it in browser, receive audio from mic and send it back to Astrisk.

And what shoud I choose for streaming audio IN/OUT as backend? XMPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  There isn't a standard way (currently) to do what you are looking to do.  You need something to help you out.  This is often done in the form of a Flash application.

Google actually uses a browser plugin from [Vidyo](http://www.vidyo.com/) to make this happen effectively.